# Send push notification via HTTP post request

Tags: rest, push-notification

I am encountering an issue with sender authentication while attempting to send push notifications using VAPID keys. I would appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide.

Here's a brief overview of the problem:

I have a website where I would like to send push notifications to subscribed users.
I obtained VAPID keys, including the private and public keys, from my backend service.
I'm using Make to send a POST request to the registered endpoint (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/eQjmDusXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX).
I have set the required headers in Postman, including the Authorization header with the value key=UilK0jWcZ9XXXXXXX and the Content-Type header as application/json.
I have also included the VAPID public key in the Crypto-Key header as p256ecdsa=BHFRSXXXXXXXXXvF1iUjVzVqt4XXXXXXXXXaE.
However, when I send the request, I consistently receive the error message "Sender is not authenticated".

If anyone has experience with sender authentication using VAPID keys and can provide guidance on how to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your help. Alternatively, if there are any additional steps or configurations I might be missing, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have double-checked the correctness of the VAPID keys, endpoint, and headers, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue. I do not use Firebase or FCM; I solely rely on the provided VAPID keys for authentication.